# display divs with images one below another on mobile version

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have divs with images inside them. Now on a desktop version everything works great. But on a mobile version i want them to be displayed one below another but i cant make it work.
Can you help me?
here is an example code from the desktop version of divs styling

```
#leftcolumn {

width:  300px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid red;
display: block;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-bottom: 20px;   
}


#rightcolumn {

width:  300px;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid red;
display: block;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
margin-top: -220px;
margin-left: 330px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

As you can see on my desktop version i am displaying them two per row (left and right) but on my mobile version (max-width: 736) i want them displayed one below other.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of making things stack on mobile is to set their width to 100%.

The best way of doing this is in a mobile first way, setting the elements `width: 100%;` and then using a media query to change the width as the viewport increases in size, something like this:

```css
section {
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  section {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>Section 1</p>
</section>
<section>
  <p>Section 2</p>
</section>
```